# How can I make that the jvectormap plug-in works on IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jvectormap

i'm developing a web page sing the plug-in "JVectorMap". I'm using the latest version, which you can find here: http://jvectormap.com/download It works fine on FireFox, Chrome and also IE9 and IE10. Nevertheless, I need it to work on IE7 and I just can't make it work! It just shows me a blank page on the monitor and in all the other browsers, they show me the entire map with the desired characteristics.

Does someone have experienced something similar or have a guess?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do the maps on jvectormap.com work if you visit it with IE8?

Comment: Yeah, I tried and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to implement excanvas.js

Canvas tags which jvector map uses are not supported in ie8
call the plugin before any canvas tags are called and your map will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of jQuery you're using. jVectorMap seems to fail silently on IE7/8 with jQuery versions older than 1.8.0.